# What magnification would an optical microscope need to see the 1000-200μm scale?

Tags: microscopy

I would like to see the actual crystals in silicon and germanium wafers when I etch them, is this feasible with an optical microscope and if so what magnification would I need?

Comment: To make 200 microns look like 2 centimetres you need x100. So that's your answer, but it is so simple that I wonder if I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @AndrewSteane No that sounds like the correct answer, it's simple because I don't really know how any of this stuff works

Comment: If your crystals are in this range you should be able to see them with a magnifier. Or even with naked eye. If you want to see details of the crystals, it will depend on the size of these details. What you may need to see is the grain boundaries between crystallites and these may be much narrower than 200 $ \mu m $

Comment: @nasu I don't need to see the grain boundaries, I only need to verify with reasonable certainty that the oxide layer has been removed